# Internet Explorer file transfer received lines repeat when using Post or iframes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need to send a file from a computer to an embedded server and for test purposes have the output to Hyperterminal to see what was received.  If we look on the computer at the F12 Developer tools "Network" the Body is normally correct, but sometimes lines 3 is a duplicate of line 2.  On the server side the line received is repeated for the entire transfer.  For test purposes this is the file:

```
$A80000032W18%L6C3100D8
$A8000009EW18%LC31600D8
$A8000010AW18%LC31600D8
$A80000176W18%L532F00D8
$A800001E2W18%L22A200D8
$A800002BAW18%L393700D8
$A80000326W18%LE77600D8
$A80000392W18%L5E1900D8
$A800003FEW18%L488600D8
$A8000046AW18%LC77300D8
$A800004D6W18%L904500D8
$A80000542W18%L9F1800D8
$A800005AEW18%L76D400D8
$AEND
```

Any suggestions?  This transfer works ok with Chrome and Firefox, but not IE and Edge.

Comment: You should paste your code test case

Answer (score 0):

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>MS-Sedco Intersector Server</title>
        <link href="toplevel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        </head>
        <body>


        <form name=connect >
        <pre>




                <input id="ConnType" type="submit" name=misce onclick="connecting()" value="Connect to Radar" size="2"> 
            <input id="ConnStatus" type="hidden" name=Conn value="*DA;" size="2">
        </pre>
        </form>
        <pre>
            <input type="file" onchange='readText(this)' size="2">
        </pre>

        <pre>

            <input type="button" onclick="program_boot()" value="Program" size="2">
        </pre>

        <pre>

            <div id=BootStatus> </div>   <div id=BootAddress> </div>  <div id=b_test> </div>
        </pre>


        <form name=RTimeout>
        <input type="hidden" name=misce value="RTimeout" size="2">
        </form>

        <form id="ie-fix" name="ie-fix" action="RadarBootLoader.htm" method="POST" target="booter-loader">
          <input type="hidden" id="dataIE" name="" />
        </form>
        <iframe src="" id="boot-loader" name="boot-loader" style="display:none" width="100%" height="600"></iframe>

        </body>

        <script language="JavaScript">
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Variables global to script
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        var Temp_id;
        var txt;
        var etime;
        var index;
        var bootindex;
        var output;
        var address;
        var done = 0;
        var lastlineindex;
        var prog_state = 0;
        var sendout;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var interval;

        if ( document.getElementById("ConnStatus").value == 1 )
        {
           document.getElementById('BootStatus').innerHTML= "   Radar Boot Connected";
        }


        function readText(that){

                    if(that.files && that.files[0]){
                        reader.onload = function (e) {  
                            output=e.target.result;

                            //process text to show only lines with "@":             
                            //output=output.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /\@/).join("\n");
                            output=output.split("\n")
                            document.getElementById('BootStatus').innerHTML= output;
                            sendout = output[0];
                        };//end onload()
                        reader.readAsText(that.files[0]);
                    }//end if html5 filelist support
        }

        function alertContents(httpRequest){
            if (httpRequest.readyState == 4){
                // everything is good, the response is received
                if ((httpRequest.status == 200) || (httpRequest.status == 0)){
                txt = httpRequest.responseText;
                document.getElementById('BootStatus').innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
                if ( (httpRequest.responseText).indexOf("Load Complete") > -1 )
                {
                   prog_state = 0;
                   if ( done )
                   {
                      //done = 0;
                  //bootindex = 0;
                  clearInterval(etime);
                      document.getElementById('BootStatus').innerHTML = "   Program Finished !!!";
                   }
                   else
                   {
                  //clearInterval(etime);
                      //etime = setTimeout( "timeout()", 1);
                      //document.getElementById('BootStatus').innerHTML = " Program Radar Flash Memory";
                      bootindex++;
                  sendout = output[bootindex];
                          if ( (output[bootindex]).indexOf("END") > -1)
                  {
                     done = 1;
                  }
                          else if ( (output[bootindex]).indexOf("$A") > -1)
                  {
                     address = "0x" + (output[bootindex]).substr(2, 8);
                         document.getElementById('BootAddress').innerHTML= "    " + address;          
                  }
                  //console.log(sendout);

                  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    send_with_ajax('RadarBootLoader.htm');
                  } else {
                    // Here is the IE fix test code
                    var iframe = document.getElementById("boot-loader");
                    var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

                    document.getElementById("dataIE").value = sendout;
                    document.getElementById("ie-fix").submit();
                    interval = setInterval(iframe_loaded, 2000);
                  }
                   }
                }
                //alert(bootindex);
                    //alert( "The response was: " + httpRequest.status + httpRequest.responseText);
                //alert( (httpRequest.responseText).indexOf("bindex") ); 
                //alert(document.getElementById("BootInd").value);
                }else{
                    alert('There was a problem with the request. ' + httpRequest.status + httpRequest.responseText);
                }
            }
        }

        function iframe_loaded() {
          var iframe = document.getElementById("boot-loader");
          var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
          var httpRequest = {
            readyState: 4,
            status: 200,
            responseText: "Load Complete"
          };

          console.log(iframeDoc.readyState);
          if (iframeDoc.readyState == "complete") {
            clearInterval(interval);
            alertContents(httpRequest);
          }
        }

        function send_with_ajax(url)
        {
            var http_request = false;

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            { // Mozilla, Safari,...
                    http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        if (http_request.overrideMimeType)
                {
                            //http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
                        }
                }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject)
            { // IE
                 try {
                            http_request = new ActiveXObject("text/xml");
                     }
                     catch(e){
                   try
                   {
                            http_request = new ActiveXObject("text/xml");
                           }
                   catch (e)
                   {
                            try
                    {
                                    http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                            }
                    catch (e) {}
                          }
                  }
                }

                if (!http_request)
            {
                    alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
                        return false;
                }

                document.getElementById('b_test').innerHTML = bootindex;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
              http_request.onreadystatechange = function() { alertContents(http_request); };
                  http_request.open('POST', url, true);
              http_request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
              http_request.setRequestHeader('Content-Encoding', "gzip");
                  http_request.send(sendout);
            } else {
              iframe_loaded();
            }
        }


        function connecting()
        {
           document.getElementById('BootStatus').innerHTML= "   Connecting Radar Boot Loader";
        }

        function program_boot()
        {
           document.getElementById('BootStatus').innerHTML= "   Waiting Radar Echo";
           etime = setTimeout( "timeout()", 10000);
           prog_state = 1;
           send_with_ajax('RadarBootLoader.htm');
        }

        function timeout()
        {
           if ( prog_state == 1 )
           {
              done = 0;
              bootindex = 0;
              alert("Can not Program Flash Memory !!");
              document.getElementById('BootStatus').innerHTML= " ";
              clearInterval(etime);
              document.RTimeout.submit();
           }
           /*else
           {
              clearInterval(etime);
              send_with_ajax('RadarBootLoader.htm');
              document.getElementById('b_test').innerHTML = bootindex;
              //etime = setTimeout( "timeout()", 10);
           }*/
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Infinite loop with delay
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        function loop()
        {
           bootindex = 0;
        }


        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Run
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        window.onload=loop;


        </script>
        </html>
```